# GWT: example of an "Admin" and "Normal-mode" application

Tags: gwt, module, admin

I am using GWT (and GWT-Plateform) and GAE, and I would like to have an Admin and a Normal-mode of my application.
I read this post https://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2009/11/19/tips-on-organizing-gwt-modules/#comment-5064 and I would like to see a complete project structure of an application using an Admin and a Normal-mode application. Do you know any sample code of this case (with GWT and GAE if possible...and with GWTP would be perfect) ?

In the link, M. Chandler says that I could have 3 modules (admin, app, common) and just 2 entry point (admin and app). Admin and app inherits common. But I do not know more stuffs such as : 
 - I am using "Client Bundle" so will it be possible to have my resource folder just inside the "common module". Will it works ? Do I need just one CSS for the 2 modules (admin and normal-mode) ?
 - Does my whole domain model needs to be in the common module ?

Any recommendation about how to structure a code with an Admin module using GWT is welcome.
**My current problem** is that I do not know how to do this with Eclipse (should I copy paste the "client", "server", "share" folders of the "app" package and to add them in a new package named "admin" and then to delete and modify some files ? It seems complicated...or is there just some minimal files and configurations to do ?)

Thanks you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy...

check this link: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Security_and_Authentication

You need two entry points.

- First for Normal-Mode
- Second for Admin-Mode

Everything for admin mode is unter the path /admin/...

In the web.xml you configure now the security constraints in web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

For the user registration and login control you can use the USERS-Api from Google:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview

Comment: Thanks you for the links, it is also interessing, but your answer is more about GAE rather than GWT. Using 2 entry points in GWT, I do not know how would be the war/WEB-INF/web.xml for example because they are talking about a "default page to serve" (should I put the Admin or the Normal page.html), and I think I cannot have 2 web.xml so I need to configure the servlets for the 2 cases etc...So I really would like a complete example or explanation (to also see how the admin.gwt.xml and the normal.gwt.xml file ares configured to inherit to the common.gwt.xml).

Comment: Sorry, i didn't recognice that you don't have app enginge. But anyway, the securtity mechanism is the same. Its java security mechanism. check out this link: [here](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2010/02/04/basics-of-gwt-authentication/)